# Match all words from given string where words does not have only lower case letters or only upper case letters

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to retrieve only those words from given string which are not all CAPS and all Lower or only first letter is upper

For example in below sentence all should be extracted except first 4 words:

> a abcd Hello AJP

```
string str = "a abcd Hello AJP lbl_Description MHz AssignExistingUserOptionText _BTHAudClassDrv_KEYWORD A_dd actelisMetaLOOP AudEngineStream_BeginStreamSwitch_Enter AudEngineStream_BeginEOS Bo_th btnChange C_hange CDs CHECK_AND_CHANGE_ACCESS_MASKS checkBox1 CIMObjectPath ciscoISLvlan comboEmailAccounts D_elete CSVFS_ReFS D_HCP DADOrNUDReply DECnet IPv4 kJ kPa LAlt  mL N_o tabPage11 uAPSD VLANs YCbCr"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it  using `Split` method and LINQ:

```
var result = str.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Where(x => !x.All(char.IsUpper) &&
                            !x.All(char.IsLower) &&
                            !(char.IsUpper(x[0]) &&
                              x.Skip(1).All(char.IsLower)))
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Nice solution, but the third condition should be !(char.IsUpper(x[0]) && char.IsLower(/* the rest of the string */))

Comment: Really a great solution. But I still don't know the complete split option so I would like to use (//b) boundary regex